# Dependencies where not copied locally (depclean warning)

Tags: maven, dependencies

I clone the castor depclean repository.
I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/castor-software/depclean#installing-and-building-from-source)
But the depclean analysis starts with a depclean warning showing this message

```
Dependencies where not copied locally
```

And after this the report got generated successfully but it doesn't tell the size of dependencies. Only "size unknown" is printed in place of actual size.

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] depclean-parent-pom                                                [pom]
[INFO] depclean-core                                                      [jar]
[INFO] depclean-maven-plugin                                     [maven-plugin]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< se.kth.castor:depclean-parent-pom >------------------
[INFO] Building depclean-parent-pom 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT                        [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- depclean-maven-plugin:2.0.1:depclean (default-cli) @ depclean-parent-pom ---
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting DepClean dependency analysis
[INFO] Skipping because packaging type pom.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< se.kth.castor:depclean-core >---------------------
[INFO] Building depclean-core 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT                              [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- depclean-maven-plugin:2.0.1:depclean (default-cli) @ depclean-core ---
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting DepClean dependency analysis
[WARNING] Dependencies where not copied locally
-------------------------------------------------------
 D E P C L E A N   A N A L Y S I S   R E S U L T S
-------------------------------------------------------
USED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [6]: 
    org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.3.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:2.0.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.ow2.asm:asm:7.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:3.3.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.jetbrains:annotations:17.0.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
USED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [2]: 
    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1:compile (size unknown)
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2:test (size unknown)
USED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [2]: 
    org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
POTENTIALLY UNUSED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [0]: 
POTENTIALLY UNUSED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [4]: 
    org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16:provided (size unknown)
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2:test (size unknown)
    org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.2:test (size unknown)
    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.8.0-beta4:compile (size unknown)
POTENTIALLY UNUSED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [39]: 
    log4j:log4j:1.2.17:compile (size unknown)
    org.jheaps:jheaps:0.9:compile (size unknown)
    com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.3:compile (size unknown)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.6.0:compile (size unknown)
    com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3:compile (size unknown)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.3.3:compile (size unknown)
    org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14:compile (size unknown)
    com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:3.2.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0:test (size unknown)
    com.google.inject:guice:no_aop:4.2.1 (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:1.4.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:1.4.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:1.4:compile (size unknown)
    javax.inject:javax.inject:1:compile (size unknown)
    javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.6.2:test (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.6.2:test (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0:test (size unknown)
    aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0:compile (size unknown)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.25:compile (size unknown)
    org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.0.0:compile (size unknown)
    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:1.4.1:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:1.4.1:compile (size unknown)
    junit:junit:4.13:test (size unknown)
    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1:compile (size unknown)
    javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0:compile (size unknown)
    commons-io:commons-io:2.5:compile (size unknown)
    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3:test (size unknown)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:1.4:compile (size unknown)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.6.2:compile (size unknown)
```

Also this warning is generating only for depclean core, not for other modules. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/904qH.png)

Can anyone help me with this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got it.
The problem was occurring because I run the project on my C-Drive(default) where probably depClean doesn't have any write access due to which depClean was unable to copy the dependencies locally.
Therefore, I tried to run the project on my D-drive and hola! it runs successfully.
One can also give write access to C-Drive to overcome this problem.
Here are the new results...

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] depclean-parent-pom                                                [pom]
[INFO] depclean-core                                                      [jar]
[INFO] depclean-maven-plugin                                     [maven-plugin]
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< se.kth.castor:depclean-parent-pom >------------------
[INFO] Building depclean-parent-pom 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT                        [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- depclean-maven-plugin:2.0.1:depclean (default-cli) @ depclean-parent-pom ---
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting DepClean dependency analysis
[INFO] Skipping because packaging type pom.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< se.kth.castor:depclean-core >---------------------
[INFO] Building depclean-core 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT                              [2/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- depclean-maven-plugin:2.0.1:depclean (default-cli) @ depclean-core ---
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting DepClean dependency analysis
-------------------------------------------------------
 D E P C L E A N   A N A L Y S I S   R E S U L T S
-------------------------------------------------------
USED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [6]: 
    org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.3.0:compile (832 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.2:compile (624 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:3.3.0:compile (257 KB)
    org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1:compile (118 KB)
    org.jetbrains:annotations:17.0.0:compile (18 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:2.0.0:compile (4 KB)
USED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [2]: 
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2:test (150 KB)
    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1:compile (55 KB)
USED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [8]: 
    org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.6.2:compile (211 KB)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.3.3:compile (200 KB)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.6.2:test (94 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.6.2:compile (57 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.6.0:compile (51 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.6.2:compile (26 KB)
    org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0:test (7 KB)
    org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0:test (2 KB)
POTENTIALLY UNUSED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [0]: 
POTENTIALLY UNUSED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [4]: 
    org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16:provided (1 MB)
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2:test (204 KB)
    org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.2:test (62 KB)
    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.8.0-beta4:compile (12 KB)
POTENTIALLY UNUSED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [33]: 
    com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android:compile (2 MB)
    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1:compile (490 KB)
    log4j:log4j:1.2.17:compile (478 KB)
    junit:junit:4.13:test (372 KB)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.3:compile (370 KB)
    commons-io:commons-io:2.5:compile (203 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.2:compile (189 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:1.4.1:compile (176 KB)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.6.2:test (170 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:1.4.1:compile (163 KB)
    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:3.2.1:compile (162 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:1.4.1:compile (145 KB)
    org.jheaps:jheaps:0.9:compile (131 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.25:compile (83 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:3.6.2:compile (65 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.6.2:compile (46 KB)
    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3:test (43 KB)
    javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0:compile (43 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.6.2:compile (43 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.6.2:compile (41 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:1.4.1:compile (35 KB)
    org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.0.0:compile (30 KB)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:1.4:compile (27 KB)
    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2:compile (19 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:3.6.2:compile (14 KB)
    com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3:compile (13 KB)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:1.4:compile (13 KB)
    com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1:compile (8 KB)
    javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0:compile (5 KB)
    aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0:compile (4 KB)
    org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14:compile (3 KB)
    javax.inject:javax.inject:1:compile (2 KB)
    com.google.inject:guice:no_aop:4.2.1 (size unknown)
Creating depclean-results.json, please wait...
[INFO] depclean-results.json file created in: D:\castor\depclean\depclean-core\depclean-results.json
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< se.kth.castor:depclean-maven-plugin >-----------------
[INFO] Building depclean-maven-plugin 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT                      [3/3]
[INFO] ----------------------------[ maven-plugin ]----------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- depclean-maven-plugin:2.0.1:depclean (default-cli) @ depclean-maven-plugin ---
-------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting DepClean dependency analysis
-------------------------------------------------------
 D E P C L E A N   A N A L Y S I S   R E S U L T S
-------------------------------------------------------
USED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [14]: 
    org.assertj:assertj-core:3.19.0:test (4 MB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.0:compile (617 KB)
    com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6:compile (234 KB)
    commons-io:commons-io:2.5:compile (203 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-project:3.0-alpha-2:compile (139 KB)
    com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension:itf-jupiter-extension:0.9.0:test (47 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:3.6.0:compile (46 KB)
    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-dependency-tree:3.0.1:compile (35 KB)
    org.whitesource:maven-dependency-tree-parser:1.0.6:compile (35 KB)
    se.kth.castor:depclean-core:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile (34 KB)
    org.apache.maven.plugin-testing:maven-plugin-testing-tools:3.3.0:compile (28 KB)
    com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension:itf-assertj:0.9.0:test (16 KB)
    org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:3.6.0:compile (13 KB)
    com.soebes.itf.jupiter.extension:itf-extension-maven:0.9.0:test (9 KB)
USED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [6]: 
    org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16:provided (1 MB)
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2:test (204 KB)
    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2:test (150 KB)
    org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.2:test (62 KB)
    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha1:compile (55 KB)
    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.8.0-beta4:compile (12 KB)
USED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [57]: 
    com.google.guava:guava:25.1-android:compile (2 MB)
    org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.3.0:compile (832 KB)
    org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:3.2.6:compile (508 KB)
    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1:compile (490 KB)
    com.google.code.google-collections:google-collect:snapshot-20080530:compile (489 KB)
    log4j:log4j:1.2.17:compile (478 KB)
    junit:junit:4.13:compile (372 KB)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.3:compile (370 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:3.3.0:compile (257 KB)
    commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4:compile (255 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-compat:3.0-alpha-2:compile (232 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:1.0-beta-3.0.5:compile (204 KB)
    org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:0.3.3:compile (200 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:1.3.1:compile (177 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.6.0:compile (173 KB)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.6.2:test (170 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-project-builder:3.0-alpha-2:compile (165 KB)
    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:3.2.1:compile (162 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.6.0:compile (162 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:1.3.1:compile (156 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:1.3.1:compile (145 KB)
    org.jheaps:jheaps:0.9:compile (131 KB)
    org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:3.4:compile (130 KB)
    org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:0.9.0.M2:compile (130 KB)
    org.ow2.asm:asm:9.1:compile (118 KB)
    org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.6.2:test (94 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:3.6.0:compile (65 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.6.0:compile (53 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:2.5.2:compile (51 KB)
    org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-beta-4:compile (50 KB)
    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3:compile (43 KB)
    javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0:compile (43 KB)
    commons-logging:commons-logging-api:1.1:compile (43 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:3.6.0:compile (43 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:3.6.0:compile (42 KB)
    org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:1.3.1:compile (36 KB)
    org.sonatype.spice:model-builder:1.3:compile (34 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:1.1:compile (34 KB)
    org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:2.0.0:compile (30 KB)
    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:2.0.11:compile (28 KB)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:1.4:compile (27 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:3.6.0:compile (26 KB)
    stax:stax-api:1.0.1:compile (25 KB)
    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2:compile (19 KB)
    org.jetbrains:annotations:17.0.0:compile (18 KB)
    org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:3.6.0:compile (14 KB)
    com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.3:compile (13 KB)
    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:1.4:compile (13 KB)
    com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:1.1:compile (8 KB)
    org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0:test (7 KB)
    javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0:compile (5 KB)
    aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0:compile (4 KB)
    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:2.0.0:compile (4 KB)
    org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:1.14:compile (3 KB)
    javax.inject:javax.inject:1:compile (2 KB)
    org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0:test (2 KB)
    com.google.inject:guice:no_aop:4.2.1 (size unknown)
POTENTIALLY UNUSED DIRECT DEPENDENCIES [0]: 
POTENTIALLY UNUSED INHERITED DEPENDENCIES [0]: 
POTENTIALLY UNUSED TRANSITIVE DEPENDENCIES [0]: 
Creating depclean-results.json, please wait...
[INFO] depclean-results.json file created in: D:\castor\depclean\depclean-maven-plugin\depclean-results.json
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for depclean-parent-pom 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] depclean-parent-pom ................................ SUCCESS [  0.828 s]
[INFO] depclean-core ...................................... SUCCESS [06:11 min]
[INFO] depclean-maven-plugin .............................. SUCCESS [12:40 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18:52 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-04-13T11:37:00+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```